# The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type undefined : BASIC AUTH

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, basic-authentication

I have this basic auth set up in `middleware.js`

```
const config = require('config');
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const token = config.get('restServerToken');


app.use(basicAuth({ authorizer: myAuthorizer }))

function myAuthorizer(username) {
    const userMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(username, [token])

    return userMatches
}

module.exports.myAuthorizer = myAuthorizer;
```

When i try to call the method in `sever.js` by

```
const middleware = require('./middleware/middleware')
middleware.myAuthorizer();
```

I get the error saying:"The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type undefined"

When i used this Auth in the same module everything worked. 
Obviously I am doing something wrong in the module exports process, can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `middleware.myAuthorizer();` you are not passing username for `basicAuth.safeCompare(username, [token])`.

Comment: That username should be sent by the user when a POST request is processed.

Comment: how it will be passed itself to `middleware.myAuthorizer();`?